# Display PDF on new tab after ajax call MVC C#

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I am new at C# and I want to display a newly and dynamically created PDF to the web browser client side, on a new tab, using HttpResponseMessage.

The PDF created is valid.
This is my controller code :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage ShowPDF()
    {

        MemoryStream ms = new GetPDF();
        Byte[] bytes = ms.GetBuffer();

        HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.pdf");

        result.Content = new StreamContent(ms);
        result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");

        return result;
    }
```

After clicking on button on HTML page, nothing is happening, no error but no new pdf displayed too. I tried using both MemoryStream or Buffer, but nothing seems to work.

EDIT

Here is my view code :

```
        <button id="GetPDF" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">GET PDF</button>
```

Javascript :

```
    $('#GetPDF').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("ShowPDF", "Controller")',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
             //Showing something but what
            },
            error: function ( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
             //Showing error message
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: What button? You've shown no button. Have you tried debugging the code? Making sure that your action method is reached, etc?

Comment: I have edited my post, and yes my action method is being called.

Comment: nothing is happening at least partly because you don't do anything with the result of your ajax call. Unless you have missed out the contents of the "success" callback in your example? And it's good that your action method is called, so have you checked that there is definitely content returned in the response?

Comment: Yes there is content returned (in data in ajax function). It also manages to go into success.

What I don't know is if it is my method that doesn't work, and also what to put inside ajax success function to display the data/PDF (which is sure has Content-Type: application/pdf ).

Comment: this is a tricky one. In your case you want to put it in a new window/tab. Since there's no URL here, just some binary data, that's tricky. Might better to abandon ajax and just do something like `window.open('@Url.Action("ShowPDF", "Controller")');`. Don't forget that browser can't natively open PDF files - it's a plugin feature. Chrome includes a plugin by default, possibly Firefox does, but IE doesn't and mobile browsers generally don't. So if there's no plugin present, you can't "display" your PDF in the browser anyway, the user will just get a download prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I managed to make it work. Here is my solution, I will optimise it tomorrow ...

Javascript :

```
        $('#GetPDF').click(function (e) {
        window.open('@Url.Action("ShowPDF", "Controller")');
    });
```

Controller Method :

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ShowPDF()
    {
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(GetPDF().ToArray());
            FileStreamResult filestream = new FileStreamResult(ms, "application/pdf");
            return filestream;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
```

GetPDF returns a MemoryStream, but closed. You have to get Byte[] element by using ToArray(), then to create another MemoryStream using constructor.

Thanks a lot to Adyson and mason for the help.